# Título das salas de chat movida de comentário não estão traduzidos

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao responder uma pergunta, o OP teve mais uma dúvida, e após alguns comentários, acabamos movendo a discussão para o chat, porém percebi que a sala criada automaticamente não estava com o título traduzido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E nem vão estar. O chat não tem tradução.

Comment: Ah bom, não fazia ideia disso